# The add_option WordPress function does not add the option

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to insert a post/page and then save the post id as an option, but the option is not saving to the database.

I am able to create the page and get the ID of it, but I am unable to save that ID to the options. The class is called at "init" and the constructor is as follows:

```
class Recipe{

    public function __construct(){
        $favorites_id = get_option("favoritesid");
        if($favorites_id <= 0){
            $my_post = array(
                     'post_title' => 'Favorites',
                     'post_content' => '',
                     'post_status' => 'publish',
                     'post_author' => 1,
                     'post_type' => 'page'
                  );

            $result_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

            if($result_id > 0){
                add_option("favoritesid", $result_id);
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: You use `add_option()` in the code, but wrote `update_option()` in the title. Please correct the question.

Comment: And please do `var_dump(add_option("favoritesid", $result_id));` to check what it returns.

Comment: Maybe it already exists? Try `echo get_option("favoritesid")`.

Comment: That is odd... all that I did was add `echo get_option("favoritesid");` before the `add_option("favoritesid", $result_id);` and the options value was set??? Why do you suppose that would be?

Comment: I'm not an WordPress expert but it looks like you are using [Options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference) to store data that is not intended to be stored as an option. I'm not sure, but it looks like this.

Answer (score 1):

Test the code in the main plugin file: (//use array_push for option)

```
class Recipe{
    public function __construct(){

        add_action('init',[$this,'test']);

    }
    public function test(){
        $favorites_id = get_option("favoritesid",[]);
        if($favorites_id >= 0){
            $my_post = array(
                'post_title' => 'this is test',
                'post_content' => '',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_type' => 'page'
            );
            $result=    get_page_by_title($my_post['post_title'],ARRAY_A, 'page');
         if(is_null($result)) {
             $result_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
             if ( $result_id >= 0 ) {
                 update_option( "favoritesid", $result_id );
             }
         }
         else return false;

        }


    }
}
new  Recipe;
```